# How to redirect page after the jquery ajax is call?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my Login form code.  My problem is after the statement is true. Is will not be redirect to the home page instead it's just show the home page at my index page.

How to Redirect jquery ajax at the other page after the statement is true?

HTML Code

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-group" method="post" action="actions/login_check.php">    
    <div id="result"></div> 
    <table class="table-condensed" >
        <tr><br>
          <td><input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Username" size="40"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Sign In</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" style="font-size:14px;"><a href="forgot_password.php">Forgot Password?</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

PHP code

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,sha1($_POST['password']));
$empty = "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709";

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$getUser = mysqli_fetch_array($query);


if(empty($username) or $password == $empty)
    echo "Invalid Email or Password";
elseif($username == $getUser['username'] and $password ==  $getUser['password']){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $online = "UPDATE users SET active = 1 WHERE username = '".$username."'";
    mysqli_query($con,$online);
    header("Location: ../home.php");
    $_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
}else
    echo "Invalid Email or Password";
```

jQuery Ajax

```
    $("button#submit").click(function(){

    if( $("#username").val == "" || $("#password").val == "")
        $("div#result").html("Please enter username and password");
    else
        $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
            $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
            function(data) {
                $("div#result").html(data);
            }
         );

         $("#myForm").submit(function(){
            return false;
         });
});
```

Comment: You can't redirect on the server when doing an ajax call, it has no effect what so ever on the page doing the ajax call. You'd have to redirect in the javascript instead, but then why do an ajax request at all when you can just redirect to the page instead

Comment: So what your suggestion? Not to use ajax?

Comment: If you're just going to redirect anyway, then yes, why would you use ajax, all you're doing in the success handler is appending some HTML, and that HTML will be lost once you redirect anyway

Comment: You should first know how ajax works! Ajax is a sub request made by browser. You are telling that subrequest to redirect to a new page and expecting the main window to redirect!!! You need to return success from the server and on the client side, redirect using `window.location`

Comment: I just change header("location") to window.location.href  . just to redirect it after the statement is true    
 mysqli_query($con,$online);?>
 <script>window.location.href=('home.php');</script>
 <?php $_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();

Comment: Im just using ajax because you know that I am Validating also in login form.  I just use ajax so if the statement is false it will not reload the page again

Answer (score 2):

In the POST response, you can use `window.location.href`

```
function(data) {
    $("div#result").html(data);
    window.location.href=<homepageurl> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.8, you can use [.done](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to redirect the user after a successful jquery `.post`.

```
  .done(function() {
    window.location.href='http://www.successpage.com'; 
  })
```

i.e.:

```
$("button#submit").click(function(){

if( $("#username").val == "" || $("#password").val == "")
    $("div#result").html("Please enter username and password");
else
    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(data) {
            $("div#result").html(data);
        }).done(function() {
    window.location.href='http://www.successpage.com'; 
  });

     $("#myForm").submit(function(){
        return false;
     });

});
```

Comment: Why to use `.done` function? Since it can help OP but for better understanding you should have include more information.

Comment: Hi @KeepCoding, I'm answering a direct question: "__How to redirect page after the jquery ajax call?__" also, I've included a link to jquery `post`manual, so the OP can read more.

Comment: thank you Sir. glad now it can best help everyone who will read it.

Comment: You're welcome @KeepCoding, no need for Sir, Pedro is enough :))

Comment: Pedro, I try your code, but if the statement is false it will redirect also to the Link page. How to handle it?

Comment: Use `.fail()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are plently of options.
1) You can assign **window.location.href** the URL which you want to redirect. But there is a problem.

Using ajax, data loads asynchronously, so there might be cases when the page redirects in between the ajax response.

**To overcome this problem, use .done() method to redirect when the ajax is finished**. Inside that done() method, pass an anonymous function, and use window.location.href inside it. 

2) You can also use .load() method which is also the short hand for .ajax() to perform page load without the page refresh which gives user a sense of redirection. *So its your choice. Pick any one!*

Answer (score 0):

Just try window.location

```
success: function (response) {
               if (response.d == true) {
                    window.location = "directed_page";
                }
            },
```

or try to use

```
window.location.replace()
```